# Проблема RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, redbeanphp

Всем привет

у меня есть ошибка

> An error occurred: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Я делаю `insert` и у меня не `id` а `idletter` изменить не могу так как база использует другой проект, я так понимаю сам redbean работает строго с `id`
помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, или может есть какой то костыль?

Прошу писать тем кто работал с ORM https://redbeanphp.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Да, в RedBean хардкодом вбит **id** в качестве primary key:

https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean/blob/c3cceb5811a6a27593b163682a124ec25bcb430d/RedBeanPHP/QueryWriter/MySQL.php#L163

https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean/blob/c3cceb5811a6a27593b163682a124ec25bcb430d/RedBeanPHP/QueryWriter/PostgreSQL.php#L181

https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean/blob/44229acdf493e2229c1e33e3add211f23c05ee4d/RedBeanPHP/Repository/Fluid.php#L199

https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean/blob/c3cceb5811a6a27593b163682a124ec25bcb430d/RedBeanPHP/QueryWriter/AQueryWriter.php#L836

Решить проблему можно, написав класс, который был бы унаследован от конкретного `QueryWriter` (имеется в виду, что если Вы работаете с MySql, то наследоваться стоит от `RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\MySQL`), и переопределив в нем методы, в которые отвечает за сохранение сущности (как минимум `updateRecord()` и `insertRecord()`) так, чтобы они "научились" понимать другие поля кроме id. Как Вы это сделаете, вобьете ли костыль под отдельную таблицу, или попробуете добавить возможность параметризировать primary key - дело Ваше. Потом этот класс наследник Вам будет необходимо подключить в проекте, вот пример кода:

```
    $oldToolBox = R::getToolBox();
    $oldAdapter = $oldToolBox->getDatabaseAdapter();
    $customWriter = new CustomPKWriterMySQL( $oldAdapter );
    $newRedBean = new OODB( $customWriter );
    $newToolBox = new ToolBox( $newRedBean, $oldAdapter, $customWriter );
    R::configureFacadeWithToolbox( $newToolBox );
```

Comment: проблему надо решать отказом от использования этого кошмара программиста